# What's the secret to "real" oscilloscopes

Tags: oscilloscope, diy

Okay, so at some point we've all connected things to a sound card input or an arduino analog input pin and said "look, mom! I made and oscilloscope!"

And, yes, technically you can get a waveform, but I want a real scope and there are three critical drawbacks with this hobby approach as I see it:

1. overvoltage protection
2. DC offset
3. sample rate

The first two can obviously be overcome by throwing a few more components at the problem, but that last one...  That's what I don't understand.

How do the real oscilloscopes do it?  How do they suck in like 1-2 GIGA samples per second??  Is it some proprietary secret sauce?  Is it moving up to expensive DSP/FPGA hardware?

Or, in other words, is designing a real scope with a decent sample rate achievable for the hobbyist or is it "big boys only" game?

Comment: They use expensive high performance ADC's whose input and digital output require extreme design care.  And they use multiple ones taking time-interleaved turns, with the outputs tuned and combined in an FPGA or similar.  This has been asked before, it's not really a fitting question since while you can do much better than a soundcard and with care get into the hundreds of megasamples, you aren't building a gigasample scope based on the answer to an SO question.  Even the economics don't work out - the scope manufacturers are getting deals on binned ADCs that you as an individual cannot.

Comment: I'd be interested to see how you get DC into a soundcard. That's unattainable as far as I know because of AC coupling.

Comment: @Andyaka back in the day the instructions to convert a sound card to oscilloscope included removal of AC coupling capacitors.

Comment: Just conveying a multi-GHz signal so as to reach the interleaved ADCs that Chris mentions is an area of study all by itself. If you look at a breakdown of the probe to the ADC sampling bank, you will see what may look quite mysterious to you yet is crucially and carefully designed. At high freq, capacitor=wire and inductor=open (approaching, anyway.) Just running a straight wire from point A to B may mean you created an "open" between them. That input section layout is very interesting to study.

Comment: Look at the "Red Pitaya" FPGA project. It'll give you some idea what's involved (and may be a good starting point for you)

Comment: @jonk, say rather that at high frequency every component is an inductor (Including poorly thought out board traces), except inductors that are most likely capacitors! High speed analog is funky!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How do the real oscilloscopes do it? How do they suck in like 1-2 GIGA samples per second??

> Is it some proprietary secret sauce?

Sure, for some, it is; especially if you're actually into high-bandwidth sensing, not some "beginner scope", with > 10 Gigasamples, there's little ways of dealing with this than custom ASICs.

> Is it moving up to expensive DSP/FPGA hardware?

Yep. That does it for single-digit Gigasamples these days. There's actually many FPGAs that come with specific high-rate buses (JESD204B, for example) just for ADCs and DACs; some even come with multi-gigasample/s ADCs and DACs on-chip (Xilinx RFSoC). The market force for these two  integrations doesn't come from oscilloscopes, but from cellular base stations, by the way.

But indeed, for the lower Gigasamples a second, a higher-end FPGA and a commercial of the shelf ADC will do.

> Or, in other words, is designing a real scope with a decent sample rate achievable for the hobbyist or is it "big boys only" game?

Since there are people who, as a 1 to 3 person cosultancy, build such instruments for specialty sensing applications for their customers: It depends on what your hobbies are. I'll go with: Being a "hobbyist" has the connotation of not having studied electrical engineering, got a formal electronics expert education or learnt high-speed analog and digital stuff on the job. If that's your status, this will be very hard and you'll spend a lot of time (and prototype money) on gaining the expertise to make anything beyond a couple dozen MHz working to a degree that we can consider it a basic measurement equipment more than a biased random generator. In the end, you can *buy* these ADCs and FPGAs, but neither are cheap in low quantities, the eval boards tend to cost thousands, the toolchains to program these FPGAs costs more than the eval boards...  It can be a hobby, but I think yacht regattas can get less expensive pretty quickly, if you share your yacht.

Comment: Totally agree. For example, look at Keysight’s DSAZ504A (worth as much as some houses). They literally have their own semiconductor fab at their disposal for such high-performance products.

Comment: @KevinSullivan that thing costs more *most* of houses on this planet, I'd say. And it's far from the upper end of Keysight's products: A friend of mine works for Keysight's link analyzers (next-gen DDR / PCIe links), and another one really goes where even the high-rise buildings I've lived in couldn't have paid for a single instrument: [Optical Terabit link analyzers](https://www.keysight.com/de/pd-2940671-pn-N4391B/optical-modulation-analyzer?nid=-33208.1247141&cc=DE&lc=ger).

Comment: @MarcusMüller, everyone knows that adding the word "optical" to the name of a test instrument automatically doubles the price.

Comment: @ThePhoton worse even, Keysight calls this category "Photonic Test & Measurement Products". And you know how "photonic" means you can start paying in dB€...

Comment: @MarcusMüller let me guess, your buddy works in Böblingen?

Comment: @ThePhoton good guess :)